# Is it possible to call a library written by C language on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a library written by C language, which contains some complicated mathematical algorithm. I'm not going to porting it to C# language, can I use it in my WP8 project? and How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C library in C++ libraries, specifically, inside C++ Windows Phone Runtime Component. You can then use that proxy/wrapper library straight from C#.

C# cannot access native methods without such proxy. You will have to think about data types translation and what you want to do with it exactly.

- [Native code on Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)